# I am getting 403 response code with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I was trying to get a response from the following URL: https://www.dnb.com/business-directory/industry-analysis.agriculture-forestry-sector.html

I am getting a `<403>` response code with the following error:

```
HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

I made the same request with the `Requests` library and got `200` status code but the only `scrapy` is giving me a `403` status code.

The `robot.txt` is set to `False` and `USER_AGENT` is also given but still getting `403` responses.

How can I avoid this response and get a `200` status code?

Thanks all for your answers.

[image]

Comment: Are there any docs on how to access their data? Can you successfully do that request for instance in Postman? 403 is a code the server issues when the request is not allowed. Without knowing the server code (or any documentation on how to access the data) nobody except the owner can tell why

Comment: I get a status code of 200 when I used the Requests library. The only reason is that the website is blocking scrapy to crawl the web page. Hence I wanted to know if there is a way to get 200 responses with scrapy. @derpirscher

Comment: Well then you would need to check the difference between the two requests. Probably a user agent value

Comment: Yes, I am using the user_agent with scrapy as well. Probably I need to parse cookies as well? I am not sure how?

Comment: Are you using proxies with scrapy? If so your proxied could be banned...or if you are sending a JSON payload maybe you are not sending it correctly with scrapy...

Comment: No, I am not using anything.